# Usage of a lut-File

Tags: lookup-tables

I've gotten the task to create a color lookup table for a program in C. 
The table should be stored in a lut file. Ok, I understand that "lut" stands for lookup table, but why is there this special file type?
I have seen lut-examples inside code, where they are simply stored as arrays, I understand that.
But what do I write in a file? I guess I'd just write the rgb-values into it without any brackets or commas and read it with fread(). But this also works if I saved the file as .c or whatever. So I feel that I don't quite get the idea of it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing particularly special about a lookup table file, and there is no standardized format for such files. It all depends on the trade-offs you are looking to deal with. If the table needs to be accessed at compile time, then it will probably just be a C file (as you have already seen). If it needs to be accessed at run time in a separate file, then you will need to come up with a suitable format.

"Lookup table" often implies that looking up a value will be fast. Perhaps a binary file format will be most suitable (vs. a text format that you have to parse). If you have 256 RGB values, each consisting of 3 bytes, you can look up a particular RGB value in the file by taking the color number, multiplying by 3, and seeking to that location in the file.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, Mike :) I implemented the lut as an xml.

Comment: XML wouldn't have been my first choice, but I'm a strong believer that if it solves your problem, that's awesome! :-)

Comment: Err.. I'm a newbie to performance questions. But my decision was based on the requirement, that users should be able to make their on color table that can be loaded into the program and xml is quite easy to read. But I am open to any other idea.

Comment: Per the requirements, it sounds like you have a good solution. Good work.